# Not able to reload the page in jquery mobile 1.4.5

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I need to reload the same page in jquery mobile(v 1.4.5) i tried the following but not reloaded.

```
$( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#editpage", { allowSamePageTransition:true,reload: true} );
```

and this also tried.

```
$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer( "change", "#editpage", { allowSamePageTransition:true,reload: true} );
```

but not get success.

How to reload the same page in jquery mobile.

Answer (score 1):

this works for me

```
jQuery.mobile.changePage(window.location.href, {
        allowSamePageTransition: true,
        transition: 'none',
        changeHash:false,
        reloadPage: true
     });
```

in your case

```
jQuery.mobile.changePage("#editpage", {
        allowSamePageTransition: true,
        transition: 'none',
        changeHash:false,
        reloadPage: true
     });
```